# CSS3 3d rotation bug - android mobiles

Tags: android, css, css-transforms, image-rotation

I seem to have come across a weird bug on Android devices.

When I rotate an element with an image along the y axis, the image seems to duplicate and squash. I have included screenshots & code to illustrate.

Before rotation wrapper CSS:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotateY(90deg);
```

After rotation wrapper CSS:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotateY(0deg);
```

[1]Before: : https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6bMJ.jpg

[2]After: : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvo8u.png

Has anyone come across this? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue by simply viewing the images? I mean they are helpful, but a bit of code would be awesome

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your reply.

Apologies for delay in replying on my own part. The site can be viewed at http://goo.gl/bdRlUC, does that help?